# Copy pasting a excel column from one excel document to another

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am going crazy here. My code works but the "was2.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value = c.value" line is not saving no matter what I do. I keep getting a "int object has no attribute value" error message. Any ideas or suggestions ?

````
import openpyxl as xl;
from openpyxl import load_workbook;

# opens the source excel file
#"C:\Users\wwwya\Desktop\mkPox.xlsx" <-- needs to have double backwords slash for xl to understand

mkPox ="C:\\Users\\wwwya\\Desktop\\mkPox.xlsx"
wbMonkey1 = xl.load_workbook(mkPox)
ws1 = wbMonkey1.worksheets[0]

# opens the destination excel file
mkPaste ="C:\\Users\\wwwya\\Desktop\\mkPaste.xlsx"
wbPaste2 = xl.load_workbook(mkPaste)
ws2 = wbPaste2.active

# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file
for row in range(2, mr + 1):
    for column in "B":  #Here you can add or reduce the columns
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        c = ws1[cell_name].value # the value of the specific cell
        print(c)
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=2).value = c.value

# saving the destination excel file
wbPaste2.save(str(mkPaste))```
````

Comment: can you try `wbPaste2.save() ` at the end, without adding the argument and see if that helps at all

Comment: Try `c;` instead of `c.value` - `ws2.cell(row=2, column=2).value = c`

Comment: I have tried both these recommendations. The code runs but it wont save anything to the excel sheet.

Comment: This code does nothing otherwise it would raise an exception. It also looks like it was thrown together using copy & paste.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a couple of issues around this section

```
c = ws1[cell_name].value # the value of the specific cell
print(c)
# writing the read value to destination excel file
ws2.cell(row=2, column=2).value = c.value
```

You assigned c already to the 'value' of the cell, **ws1[cell_name].value** therefore c is a literal equal to the value of that cell, it has no attributes. When you attempt to assign the cell value on the 2nd sheet, you just want the variable 'c', as @norie indicated.
The next issue in that section is that is the row and column for **ws2.cell** doesn't change. Therefore whatever you are writing to the 2nd sheet is always  going to cell 'B2' making the iteration thru the 1st sheet a waste of time, only cell 'B2' will have a value and it will be from the last cell in column 'B' in the 1st sheet.
Also there is no need to include a file path/name in **wbPaste2.save(str(mkPaste))** if saving to the same file. It's only necessary if you want to save to a different path and filename. However if you include the filename it would still work. There is no need to cast as string since mkPaste is already a string.

The code example below shows how you can simplify the whole operation to a few lines;
Note; the loop uses enumerate to create two variables that update each loop iteration.

```
for enum, c in enumerate(ws1['B'][1:], 2):
```

**enum** is used as the row position in ws2, the '2' in the enumerate function means the enum variable initial value is 2, so the first row to be written on the 2nd sheet is row 2.
**c** is the cell object from ws1, column 'B'. The loop starts at the second cell due to the [1:] param in line with your code starting the copy from row 2.
There is no need to use intermediary variables, just assign each cell in the 2nd sheet the value of the corresponding cell in the 1st sheet then save the file.

```
import openpyxl as xl;

mkPox ="C:\\Users\\wwwya\\Desktop\\mkPox.xlsx"
wbMonkey1 = xl.load_workbook(mkPox)
ws1 = wbMonkey1.worksheets[0]

# opens the destination excel file
mkPaste ="C:\\Users\\wwwya\\Desktop\\mkPaste.xlsx"
wbPaste2 = xl.load_workbook(mkPaste)
ws2 = wbPaste2.active

for enum, c in enumerate(ws1['B'][1:], 2):
    ws2.cell(row=enum, column=c.column).value = c.value

# saving the destination excel file
wbPaste2.save()
```